# python iteration through stdout

Tags: python, iteration, stdout, popen

I am able to print the output of my `subprocess.popen` with:

```
output = file.stdout.read()
print output
```

I'm looking for examples of how to iterate through every like of the output to find every instance of the word FontCache and send it to a file. I don't know if I need a for loop or an if statement. I would appreciate a push in the right direction. A link to some examples would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
for output in file.stdout.readlines():
    if "FontCache" in output:
        outputfile.write(output)
```

Of course, you have to open an `outputfile` to write to.

Comment: Style suggestion: s/output/line/

Comment: Normally, that's what I use, I decided to follow the questioner's variable naming convention for some reason.